# Skipping dependencies with dojo build

Tags: dojo, dojo-build

I have .profile.js file with next string:

```javascript
...
layers: {
boot: true,
customBase: true,
"dojo/dojo": {
"app/ONEFILE"
}
```

and after build its join over thousands files in this build,

how can I skip it and join **only specified files** excluding all dependencies?